# I need Regular Expression for a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for a string that 
starts with Alphabets (no number)
max Length 8
No special characters or space. 
string can have number or _ except for starting character.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Show your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{0,7}$/i
```

For example,

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{0,7}$/i.test('a1234567'); // true
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{0,7}$/i.test('01234567'); // false
```

Comment: As noted below: `[a-z]{1}` is unnecessary. Also, your test is wrong, and will match any number of leading letters because `{1,}` will match infinite letters. So for instance: `/^[a-z]{1,}[a-z0-9_]{0,7}$/i.test("aaaa0909090");//true` is not what you want, as the tested string is 11 characters long (Not 8, as specified).

Comment: @Jesse, thanks, those were wrong. fixed

Answer (score 2):

The `\w` shorthand is for all letters, numbers and underscores. `[A-Za-z]` is overkill, the `/i` flag will get you all letters, case insensitive.

Therefore, a super simple regex for what you need is:

`/^[a-z]\w{0,7}$/i`

```
/^[a-z]\w{0,7}$/i.test("a1234567");
> true
/^[a-z]\w{0,7}$/i.test("a12345697");
> false
/^[a-z]\w{0,7}$/i.test("01234567");
> false
```

Comment: Another note, without the `i` flag, Jonathan M's `[a-z]` won't match uppercase, Neal's `[a-zA-z]` won't match uppercase (not actually sure what the mixed case will do, but probably not what you want), and IAbstractDownVoteFactor's `[a-z]{1}` is redundant, `[a-z]` will always match a single character, `{1}` is always unnecessary. Keep your regexes simple and readable!

Comment: +1, good call with `\w`.

Comment: This is wrong as it contains numbers...

Comment: @FailedDev, numbers are allowed after first character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,7}$/
```

Comment: `{1}` is redundant; it always defaults to 1.

Comment: This requires a minimum of 2 characters in the string. It doesn't match `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]{0,7}$/
```

This requires an alpha start character, and optionally allows up to 7 more characters which are either alphanumeric or underscore.

EDIT: Thanks, Jesse for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

And another version with lookaheads :)

```
if (subject.match(/^(?=[a-z]\w{0,7}$)/i)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

**Explanation :**

```
"^" +           // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"(?=" +         // Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   "[a-z]" +       // Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
   "\\w" +          // Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      "{0,7}" +       // Between zero and 7 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   "$" +           // Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
")"
```

Comment: Upvote for diversity and originality, downvote for complexity and readability. Very interesting, though. :)